Automatically delete messages in a Google Chat group and lock the group Questi
Is it possible to create a Google Apps Script code that will automatically delete all messages in a specific Google Chat group and lock the group to prevent users from leaving new messages?
I haven't tried anything yet, I'm looking for a link to any documentation on the web

"I haven't tried anything yet, looking for ..." is not a question you can ask at SO
